# SQL update query erro de sintaxe

Tags: sql, query, sql-update

Quando eu executo a seguinte update query ocorre um erro de sintaxe antes ou dentro do from:

```
UPDATE Artigos 
SET totale = entradas.sent
FROM Artigos INNER JOIN (SELECT cod_artigo, Sum([quantidade_ent]) AS sent FROM entradas GROUP BY cod_artigo)
ON Artigos.cod_artigo = Entradas.cod_artigo;
```

Estou a usar o access

Mensagem de erro:

> erro de sintaxe(operador em falta) na expressão de consulta"tmp.sent FROM Artigos INNER JOIN (SELECT cod_artigo, Sum([quantidade_ent]) AS sent FROM entradas GROUP BY cod_artigo) as tmp ON Artigos.cod_artigo = tmp.cod_artigo;"

Comment: Coloque também a mensagem de erro. Também nunca vi um `INNER` com `(SELECT)`. Pelo que sei, o `INNER` deve especificar uma tabela e não uma coluna

Comment: Veja aqui:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882212/sql-updating-from-an-inner-join

Comment: Mensagem de erro:
erro de sintaxe(operador em falta) na expressão de consulta"tmp.sent
FROM Artigos INNER JOIN (SELECT cod_artigo, Sum([quantidade_ent]) AS sent FROM entradas GROUP BY cod_artigo) as tmp
ON Artigos.cod_artigo = tmp.cod_artigo;"

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que colocando um Alias para a subquery resolva.

```
UPDATE Artigos 
SET Artigos.totale = tmp.sent
FROM Artigos INNER JOIN (SELECT cod_artigo, Sum([quantidade_ent]) AS sent FROM entradas GROUP BY cod_artigo) as tmp
ON Artigos.cod_artigo = tmp.cod_artigo;
```

Comment: não funcionou :(

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, se entendi bem sua proposta, o seguinte SQL resolve seu problema:

```
UPDATE artigos
SET    totale = tmp.sent
FROM   (SELECT  cod_artigo,
            SUM(quantidade_ent) AS sent
   FROM     entradas
   GROUP BY cod_artigo
   )
   tmp
WHERE  tmp.cod_artigo = tmp.cod_artigo;
```